# Getting Number of Combinations of Numbers That When Added are Above a Value

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How would you find the number of combinations of length 5 of numbers 1 through 10 that, when added, are above 20?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Are you familiar with *integer partitions*?

Comment: Compute Coeff $[x^{5}q^{m}] \prod_{n=1}^{10} \frac{1}{1-xq^n}$ for every $m \geq 21.$

Comment: Can you explain why this would work please?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.